# Joomla 1.5 REST interface?

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, joomla1.5

I want to query some information about articles or users from a Joomla website for my client-side application.

SOP can be ignored.  I am working with Joomla 1.5.26 and I have an account with full rights. Unfortunately, I **cannot access the source code** at the moment.

For example:

> http://example.com/index.php?option=com_content&Itemid=53

I would like something like this, but this returns full html page, not the article information.

And what if I would like to get many items at once sorted by some attribute like:

> http://example.com/index.php?option=com_content&count=10&sortBy=latest&format=xml

Would like to see something like:

```
<articles>
    <article>...<article>
    <article>...<article>
    <article>...<article>
</articles>
```

I haven't found a good explanation of the default query schemes.
Worst case scenario would be parsing the html, but I really hope there is some other way.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi! Since some time, Joomla has its own StackExchange site: [joomla.stackexchange.com](http://joomla.stackexchange.com). I recommend you asking your future [tag:joomla]-related questions there.

Answer (score 0):

**Important:** Joomla 1.5 and 2.5 are not longer maintained. Please upgrade to a stable and safe release.

But if you really insist, you can use "tmpl=component" as paremeter or just the index2.php to get the component content only (without template).

Everything else you will find under https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core